# Webscraping with Rvest: issues with login

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to webscrape data from the following website which requires me to login first: http://nationallizenzen-1zbw-1eu-137hhmrga01e8.zugang.nationallizenzen.de/zbwhtml/10836/55627/Country%20Report%20Austria%20December%202017.html?page=full.

I tried to simulate the login using advice from the following blog entry: https://riptutorial.com/r/example/23955/using-rvest-when-login-is-required

My code looks the following:

```
    user.name <- "ABC12345"
    pw <- "abcd1234"
    url.html <- "http://nationallizenzen-1zbw-1eu-137hhmrga01e8.zugang.nationallizenzen.de/zbwhtml/10836/55627/Country%20Report%20Austria%20December%202017.html?page=full"
    
    pgsession <- html_session(url.html)
    
    pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
    filled_form <- set_values(
    pgform,
    username = user.name,
    password = pw
    )
```

When I enter the URL above into my search bar, I get redirected to the following website:
https://login.nationallizenzen.de/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO?execution=e1s2.

From the HTML source code of that website I understand, that the login fields to be filled are called "username" and "password".

The object pgsession is a quite heavily nested list. I searched it extensively but it does not at all seem to resemble the HTML source code of my target website and I do not find any of these fields.

As I am completely new to HTML, I do not really understand what is happening here. My suspicion is, that my web browser gets directed to another site and that this is not replicated by Rs simulated browser session. In particular, when I type `pgform[["url"]]`, the URL does not match the one stated above (it ends with "e1s1" instead of "e1s2").

If you would have any solutions, tips or advice I would be very gratuful. Due to my bad knowledge of HTML I feel a bit lost in this.

Best regards,
Tobias

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fill the form and press on the submit button with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://nationallizenzen-1zbw-1eu-137hhmrga01e8.zugang.nationallizenzen.de/zbwhtml/10836/55627/Country%20Report%20Austria%20December%202017.html?page=full")

web_Obj_Username <- remDr$findElement("id", "username")
web_Obj_Username$sendKeysToElement(list("my_user_name"))
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE, useViewer = TRUE) 

web_Obj_Username <- remDr$findElement("id", "password")
web_Obj_Username$sendKeysToElement(list("my_password"))
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE, useViewer = TRUE) 

web_Obj_Button <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div[5]/button") # Submit button
web_Obj_Button$clickElement()
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE, useViewer = TRUE)
```

Here is an alternative approach :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
url <- "http://nationallizenzen-1zbw-1eu-137hhmrga01e8.zugang.nationallizenzen.de/zbwhtml/10836/55627/Country%20Report%20Austria%20December%202017.html?page=full"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)

web_Obj_Username <- IEApp$Document()$getElementByID("username")
web_Obj_Username$Click()
web_Obj_Username$Focus()
web_Obj_Username[["Value"]] <- "my_user_name"

web_Obj_Username <- IEApp$Document()$getElementByID("password")
web_Obj_Username$Click()
web_Obj_Username$Focus()
web_Obj_Username[["Value"]] <- "my_password"

doc <- IEApp$Document()
clickEvent <- doc$createEvent("MouseEvent")
clickEvent$initEvent("click", TRUE, FALSE)
web_Obj_Login <- IEApp$Document()$getElementsByClassName("form-element form-button")
web_Obj_Login$Item(0)$dispatchEvent(clickEvent)
```

Comment: Dear Emmanuel, thanks for your answer. Could you elaborate a bit on the command `shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')`? I understand that `shell()` runs a system command but I get the error message `'docker' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. Some explanations of the commands you run would help me debug.

Comment: My R Session aborts whenever I try to run `IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE`, do you have an idea what could be the issue?

Comment: You have to install docker which is a free open source software. To install it on Windows, you can go here : https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/. You download it, and execute the « exe ».

Comment: It is not clear for me why "IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE" generates a bug on your side. Which version of R are you using?

Comment: Also, can you try to run the code without "IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE" to see if it works? "IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE" is useful to see what is going on on the page, but it is not necessary.

Comment: The session still aborts now once I run `IEApp$Navigate(url)` (skipping the previous line). My R version is 4.0.2.

Comment: Do you use R 4.0.2 on 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: I juste tried the code on R 4.0.2 64 bit and it works very well on my end. I use Windows. Also, to install RDCOMClient, you can use the following command : install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R").

Comment: I use it on a 64bit Windows machine as well.
Running `install.packages("RDCOMClient", repos = "omegahat.net/R")` did not work when I previously tried to install the package. I installed it from github instead (`devtools::install_github("omegahat/RDCOMClient")`).
I had updated my R to Version 4.1.2 in the meantime, is there an R-version you would recommend for using the `RDCOMClient`-package?

Comment: No, on my computer, it works well on all version of R. When you install "RDCOMClient", a pop-up window will appear and ask you if you want to install it from source. You have to click yes. To the best of my knowledge, you need Rtools to compile the RCOMClient package. Did you install Rtools on your computer? To install Rtools, you just need to download the "exe" and install it : https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html.

Comment: I just installed the R package RDOMClient on R 4.1.2 64 bit with the following commands : devtools::install_github("omegahat/RDCOMClient"); install.packages("devtools"); library(devtools);